# How do you reset/revert system menus back to defaults?

Tags: menu

There are menu items missing form my System->Preference menu. Going to System->Preferences->Main Menu, the menu items are not disable, but missing entirely. How do you reset the menus back to defaults?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click the menu, click edit menus, click the "Revert" button. This is the screen you should see:

[image: This is what you should be seeing]

Comment: That was too easy, I can't believe it!

Answer (score 1):

If the first answer does not work you could try deleting your ~/.local/share/applications directory and then logout/login. Everything should have reset to the default settings.